# Divide contents of a unsigned char array into 2 halves

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, type-conversion

I am wondering if anyone can help me I am only learning c, I am trying to Divide contents of a unsigned char array into 2 halves, which the result can stored in two unsigned int's,

For example purposes, I have some code below which adds a hex value into a BYTE array, so How would split the contents of val[] into two but keep the same order

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
int main()
{
    // Sample purposes putting hex into val[8]
    int i,j;
    long long hex=0x78661EB54FE76763;
    BYTE val[8];

    for(j=0,i=7; i>=0; i--,j++){
        val[j]= (hex>>(i*8))&0xff;
    }       

    // How to split the contents of val[8] which now holds the hex

    return 0;  
}
```

I am trying to split the hex value into 78661EB5, 4FE76763 and store each one inside an unsigned int which is stored inside val[8] in my example

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `long long hex` is not a "char array", but you can try something like this, notice unsigned types throughout.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint64_t hex = 0x78661EB54FE76763;
    uint32_t lo, hi;

    hi = hex >> 32;
    lo = hex & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    printf("%08X %08X\n", hi, lo);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
78661EB5 4FE76763
```

Comment: sorry if my questain is confusing, I mean val[8] contains the hex value of 78661EB54FE76763 and this is what I am trying to split.

Comment: `val[8]` does not contain anything, it is a stepping stone. Your question asked how to split that value into 2 unsigned ints and this answer does it without any need for an 8-byte char array.

Comment: Sorry that code is confusing, I was filling BYTE val[8] with the value. I am  trying to split BYTE val[8]. I have made example less confusing

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper function that takes a pointer to an array of `unsigned char` and call it twice.

Left some things out for OP to discover.

```
unsigned long form_big_endian4(const unsigned char * x) {
  unsigned long y = TBB;           // What should the initial value be?
  for (int i = 0; i < TBD; i++) {  // How many times to loop?
    y *= TBD;                      // Hint: max value of 8 bits + 1
    y += x[i];                     
  }
  return y;
}

#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  const unsigned char val[8] =
      { 0x78, 0x66, 0x1E, 0xB5, 0x4F, 0xE7, 0x67, 0x63 };
  unsigned long half = form_big_endian4(val); // Why long: Hint how small can unsigned be?
  printf("%08lX\n", half);                    // Why 0 in format? Why `lX`?
  half = form_big_endian4(val + TBD);         // How far an offset?
  printf("%08lX\n", half);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you like to pose puzzles, you should make them solvable, what they are not really if a symbol TBD is used for different values.